# How to merge and concat in for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a following data

list = ['AA','BB','CC']

| Date | AA | BB | CC | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20220101 | True | True | True | 100 |
| 20220101 | False | False | True | 100 |
| 20220102 | False | True | True | 100 |
| 20220103 | False | True | True | 600 |
| 20220103 | True | True | False | 400 |
| 20220104 | True | True | True | 100 |
| 20220105 | False | False | True | 200 |
| 20220106 | True | True | False | 100 |

I need the following output:

| Date | AA | BB | CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20220101 | 100 | 100 | 200 |
| 20220102 | 0 | 100 | 100 |
| 20220103 | 400 | 1000 | 600 |
| 20220104 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 20220105 | 100 | 0 | 200 |
| 20220106 | 100 | 100 | 0 |

I tried

```
dp = ['AA','BB','CC']

kf = pd.DataFrame()
    
for i in dp:
    sd = df[(df[i] == True)].groupby(['Date'])['XYZ'].sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'XYZ': i})
        
    new = pd.concat([kf, sd], ignore_index = True)
```

but its not working and only getting last 'CC' in table.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use for a new DataFrame:

```
l = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']

df2 = df.copy()
df2[l] = df[l].mul(df['XYZ'], axis=0)
df2 = df2.drop('XYZ', axis=1).groupby('Date').sum()
```

output:

```
       Date   AA   BB   CC
0  20220101  100  100  200
1  20220102    0  100  100
2  20220103  400 1000  600
3  20220104  100  100  100
4  20220105    0    0  200
5  20220106  100  100    0
```

Comment: I need it grouped by Date, using this way if i groupby date then getting inflated values.

Comment: @DivyanshKumarSingh I realize the output I provided is not the correct one. It does aggregate on the date, check the update

Comment: pk = []

for i in dp:
    sd = df[(df[i] == True)].groupby(['Date'])['XYZ'].sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'XYZ': i})
    pk.append(sd)
pd.concat(pk).groupby(['Date']).sum()

This gives the desired result, Thanks